# Find bisector of lines on a given side of a line

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to find the bisector of two lines that lies on a given side of the first line. By way of picture, in the below notice the bisector I want always lies to the right of the first vector (following the direction of the arrows).

[image]

I have my data for the vectors as the initial point plus a direction. It's easy enough to find the two bisectors, but how do choose the one to the right of the initial vector?

*I realize this question is likely the same as asking whether the angle traced along the right side is convex or concave. With that knowledge I think I can easily select the correct bisector.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in the $x$-$y$ plane, once you have the bisector, say $\mathbf{c}$, of your two vectors, $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, then look at the cross-product $-\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{c}$.

By the right-hand thumb rule, if you have the correct $\mathbf{c}$ then $-\mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{c}$ will point in the positive $z$-axis direction. The incorrect $\mathbf{c}$ will point in the negative $z$-axis direction.

There is the degenerate case, $\mathbf{a} = -\mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{c}$ is parallel to both $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ and the above cross-product is $0$, but here, the required bisector is just $\mathbf{b}$.